# Wordpress in_category and has_tag conditionals doesn't work in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I want to block Wordpress articles (It is an online magazine) which were created previous to a member subscription (Using Woocommerce memberships)

I need to check that if an article belongs to a particular category, tag than execute the "if". The `in_category` or `has_tag` don't work, I have been using `is_category` up to now, but it block articles only on the category archive page. The problem is that articles need to be blocked to the root because they can appear somewhere else on the site for ex **"related articles"**.
Even the `is_tag` works, but only on the tag archive page.

Here is the code that I have below:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'date_search_filter' );

function date_search_filter($query) {
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$startdate=$wpdb->get_col("select tmpm.meta_value from tmwp_posts as tmpp inner join tmwp_postmeta as tmpm on tmpp.ID = tmpm.post_id where tmpm.meta_key = '_start_date' and tmpp.post_author = ". $user_id . " order by tmpm.meta_id desc limit 1",0);



if ( !is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_category('387')){

$query->set( 'date_query', 
    [    [
    'after'     => $startdate[0],
    'inclusive' => true,
    ]    ] 
    );
    }
  }
}
```

The code I want to check is **`if ($query->is_category('387')){`**
I don't want to use `is_single()` because it blocks every article, even products that I have.

Comment: Woocommerce product categories and product tags are Woocommerce **custom taxonomies** that will not work with `in_category()` and `has_tag()` Wordpress functions… Also those conditional functions doesn't work with a `WP_Query` using them methods like in your code.

Comment: Actually i am trying to restrict articles so its a wordpress taxonomy.